# AFNetworking iOS add curl

Tags: ios, iphone, curl, afnetworking-2

I would like to add 
`curl -H "Accept: application/json"` 
to request that Iam sending thru AFNetworking on ios. 
I don't know how to add it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to added this text in AFURLResponseSerialization.m file

```
self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/plain",@"text/html", nil];
```